# Getting 404 error With New Symfony Installation

Tags: php, symfony

New to Symfony so have installed it and tried to create a test page using their Lucky Number example.
The server is running yet when I attempt to access the URL I get a 404 error

Here is the code for the controller :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number(): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

This was saved as LuckyController.php in the CYTest/src/Controller folder

I then added the route into routes.yaml

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /CYTest/lucky/number ( I also tried without the /CYTest project folder )
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

Can't understand why I'm getting a 404..The default index page is working fine with no errors reported form the checks.
I have tried different versions as well. Locally I have 6.2.7 and on my web host I have 2.3.42

Comment: About what version are you talking about ? Symfony or PHP ? 
Also, have you tried to used the PHP8 attributes (or annotations for older php version) to declare you routes ? 
You may use the following command to debug your routes: php bin/console debug:route

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out..

I copied the symfony.exe inside the project folder and it works fine now.

Comment: There is no requirement that symfony.exe be installed in the project folder.  In fact, for multiple projects, you really only want one symfony.exe to be installed.  You do need to startup the symfony server from the project directory.  I'm guessing that is why your initial attempts failed.  By the way, the so-called `default page` really is not a page at all.  It is more of a debug page for when no routes are defined.